# Regex ignore first x characters and then match pattern

Tags: regex

```
String = '11111111111110000000000000000000110000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111110011111111111110000011110000011111111111110000000000011111111111111111010001111111111111111111110011111111111111111111111111110111112111121111111111111111111000011000001011111111111101022111101111001111111111110000001000000111111111111111000000000000011111111111111100011111111001011111111100000000000000000000000000000000100111001000000000000000000011000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000011000000000000000000000010000000000333333333'
```

I want a pattern to take out 10 characters after the first 100 so i want to have 100 - 110 then I want to compare that one and see if that string with a length of 10 have 4 zeros in a row.

How can I do this with only Regex? I have been using substring before.

Comment: The duplicate reference makes little sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

```
^.{100}(?=.{0,6}0000)(.{10})
```

Explanation:

- `^`: matches the start of the string to avoid that the pattern is used anywhere in the input
- `.{100}`: match 100 characters
- `(?=   )`: look ahead. This does not capture, but just verifies something that is still ahead.
- `.{0,6}`: 0 to 6 characters
- `0000`: literally 4 zeroes
- `(.{10})`: 10 characters, this time they are captured and can be referenced back with `\1` or `$1` depending on the flavour of regex.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could explain what the issue is with this answer?

Comment: Downvoters should atleast provide some useful comment before downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is perfect. But that matches all the characters including first 100.
In case of ignoring first 100, we can use

```
(?<=.{100})
```

To check the required pattern in last 10 characters after first 100 only, we can use

```
(?<=.{100})(?=.{0,6}0000)(.{10})
```